# Place Toast with custom layout at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toast

I have a Toast with a custom layout I want to place at the bottom of the screen, and at the same time have it fill the width of the screen. I cannot get it to work properly.

My Toast layout toast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ee222222"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

The code to display the Toast, MyToast.java:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
TextView textView = phoneToastView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18");

Toast toast = new Toast(getContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.setView(view);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

**Here is my problem:**

If I set gravity to BOTTOM, I get the Toast on the bottom of the screen. If I set gravity to FILL_HORIZONTAL, it will fill the screen horizontally. If I use both, it fills the screen horizontally, but there is a gap between the Toast and the bottom of the screen.

I think what happens, is that Android creates the view, moves it to the bottom, and *then* stretches it out. Now the text suddenly has more space, which for some screens and some texts means that it changes from 2 lines of text to just 1 line of text.

Now the view suddenly requires less vertical space, and the view is shrunk by moving the bottom edge up.

Is there a way around this? Can I force Android to do the horizontal fill *first* and *then* do the move to the bottom? Can I get the view to shrink vertically from the top instead of from the bottom?

**Answer to some of the comments:**

- I can not use Snackbar, since this Toast will be displayed when my app is in the background
- The text I'm displaying in my Toast varies in length, so I cannot predict how many lines of text it will be
- The code above is the absolute simplest where I have been able to reproduce the error

**Update:**

To be able to reproduce the issue, use the code above and run the app on a virtual device Nexus 5.

Below are links to screenshots with three different length texts. The shortest and longest texts are displayed at the bottom, the middle text gets a gap below the Toast:

- [Toast with short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyewU.png)
- [Toast with medium text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if6hl.png)
- [Toast with long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48O5A.png)

**Update 2: My solution**

My new toast layout toast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ee222222"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The new code to display the Toast, MyToast.java:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);

TextView textView1 = phoneToastView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
textView1.setText("Some text on one line");
TextView textView2 = phoneToastView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
textView2.setText("Some more text on one line");
TextView textView3 = phoneToastView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
textView3.setText("Even more text, and this text is much longer, not fitting on one line at all.");

// If I don't need the unpredictable third line of text, hide the view
textView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Toast toast = new Toast(getContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.setView(view);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

For my needs, I will mostly use textviews 1 and 2. Then the toast will be at the bottom of the screen (since they are fixed to have one line of text). In some situations, I cannot predict the length of the text, and then I use textview 3. Then the toast will not be at the bottom, but this is quite rare.

Comment: Do you mind fixing the `TextView` lines to two no matter what?

Comment: i can't reproduce it, on my device it shows correctly. Which device are you using to test?

Comment: Perhaps the best option is to use [snackbar](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Hi, it seems you forgot to include the screenshots at the end

Comment: I meant to add screenshots, but I never got it to work. The editor is always complaining that I haven't formatted my code properly when I add images. Added links to the images instead.

Comment: You don't need the LinearLayout. What happens if you use just the TextView? Move the background color, padding and namespace declarations to the TextView and remove the LinearLayout.

Comment: Updated the layout to only use the TextView, since the LinearLayout in my example code didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

> If I set gravity to BOTTOM, I get the Toast on the bottom of the screen. If I set gravity to FILL_HORIZONTAL, it will fill the screen horizontally. If I use both, it fills the screen horizontally, but there is a gap between the Toast and the bottom of the screen.

I recently encountered this issue as well. The toast has some default margins set. Thankfully the way to remove this gap is simple:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.setView(view);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

// remove the margins which cause the gap
toast.setMargin(0,0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a proper answer, but have instead used @xenolion's suggestion as a workaround.

Instead of having a single textview, I have 4 textviews, most of them fixed to one line of text and hide the ones I don't need. See my updated answer for code.